# YOLO v3 complete architecture

Tags: keras, tensorflow, object-detection, object-recognition, yolo

I am attempting to implement YOLO v3 in Tensorflow-Keras from scratch, with the aim of training my own model on a custom dataset. By that, I mean **without using pretrained weights**. I have gone through all three papers for YOLOv1, YOLOv2(YOLO9000) and YOLOv3, and find that although Darknet53 is used as a feature extractor for YOLOv3, I am unable to point out the complete architecture which extends after that - the "detection" layers talked about [here](https://itnext.io/implementing-yolo-v3-in-tensorflow-tf-slim-c3c55ff59dbe). After a lot of reading on blog posts from Medium, kdnuggets and other similar sites, I ended up with a few significant questions:

- Have I have missed the complete architecture of the detection layers (that extend after Darknet53 used for feature extraction) in YOLOv3 paper somewhere?
- The author seems to use different image sizes at different stages of training. Does the network automatically do this upscaling/downscaling of images?
- For preprocessing the images, is it really just enough to resize them and then normalize it (dividing by 255)?

Please be kind enough to point me in the right direction. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is old but YOLOv1 there is everything you need in the paper. It is not that simple to implement though.

What you are missing I think is that they first train a classification NN, this is, they removed the last few layers, and run probably with a regression head, and softmax function, the standard way you classify images. In this case, you can train in any size, (224x224 in this case); the convolution results are general.

In this way the NN learnt to extract features.

Then they load the weights without the network head, and add a different, 5 layers head that ends with 2 fully connected regression layers, and a different loss function, which is the custom one they designed, and you will have to implement.